# How to JOIN a table to itself with separate conditions from another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables in my database:

```
campuses
+----+--------+----------+--------+------+
| Id | Campus | Location | County | Year |
+----+--------+----------+--------+------+
discEnr
+----------+------------+------+----+----+
| CampusId | Discipline | Year | Ug | Gr |
+----------+------------+------+----+----+
disciplines
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
```

**The question:**
Report graduate enrollments in 2004 in ’Agriculture’ and ’Biological Sciences’ for any university that offers graduate studies in both disciplines. Report one line per university (with the two grad. enrollment numbers in separate columns), sort universities in descending order by the number of ’Agriculture’ graduate students.

I understand how to report either 'Agriculture' or 'Biological Sciences'
as follows but not both together in one output table

```
THIS WORKS FOR JUST 'Agriculture'

SELECT c.Campus, DE1.Gr Agriculture
FROM discEnr DE1
JOIN disciplines d1
  ON d1.Id = DE1.Discipline
 AND d1.Name = 'Agriculture'  
JOIN campuses c
  ON c.Id = DE1.CampusId
 AND DE1.year = 2004
ORDER BY DE1.Gr DESC;
```

My most recent attempt gives me an empty set which is not correct but I'm not really sure where to go from here:

```
SELECT c.Campus, DE1.Gr Agriculture, DE2.Gr Biology
FROM discEnr DE1
JOIN disciplines d1
  ON d1.Id = DE1.Discipline
 AND d1.Name = 'Agriculture'  
JOIN discEnr DE2
  ON DE1.CampusId = DE2.CampusId
JOIN disciplines d2
  ON d2.Id = DE2.Discipline
 AND d1.Name = 'Biological Sciences'
JOIN campuses c
  ON c.Id = DE1.CampusId
 AND DE1.year = 2004
ORDER BY DE1.Gr DESC;
```

Ultimately my output should be in the form:

```
+-----------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| campuses.Campus | discEnr.Gr Agriculture | discEnr.Gr Biology |
+-----------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` can be used in such cases but still we should go through the sample data to provide the proper suggestion or solution.

Comment: I don't know how to provide a sample data set from the program we're working off of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution that works. I'm not sure what a more elegant way would be but this does work. If you know a shorter or more readable way please feel free to post!

```
SELECT c.Campus, DE1.Gr Agriculture, DE2.Gr Biology
FROM discEnr DE1
JOIN disciplines d1
  ON d1.Id = DE1.Discipline
 AND d1.Name = 'Agriculture'
 AND DE1.Gr > 0

JOIN discEnr DE2
  ON DE1.CampusId = DE2.CampusId
JOIN disciplines d2
  ON d2.Id = DE2.Discipline
 AND d2.Name = 'Biological Sciences'
 AND DE2.Gr > 0

JOIN campuses c
  ON c.Id = DE1.CampusId
 AND DE1.year = 2004
ORDER BY DE1.Gr DESC;
```

It's actually pretty close to my original solution but in my original post I put **d1**.Name = 'Biological Sciences' instead of **d2**.Name = 'Biological Sciences'

Answer (score 0):

u can use OR operator.

```
SELECT c.Campus, DE1.Gr 
FROM discEnr DE1
JOIN disciplines d1 ON d1.Id = DE1.Discipline 
JOIN disciplines d2 ON d2.Id = DE1.Discipline 
JOIN campuses c ON c.Id = DE1.CampusId AND DE1.year = 2004
where d1.Name = 'Agriculture' or d2.Name = 'Biological Sciences'
ORDER BY DE1.Gr DESC;
```

please provide your sample dataset for us to refine the answer

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't make my post clear enough. I agree but the question requires that a campus must offer both Agriculture grads and Biology grads to qualify so OR won't work here

Comment: u have to specify some sample records of all table and also the expected output in the form of table